# Не совсем понимаю for of.. как с цикла for сделать for of?

Tags: javascript, for

```
function filterArray(numbers, value) {
  const filteredNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    const number = numbers[i];

    if (number > value) {
      filteredNumbers.push(number);
    }
  }

  return filteredNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы переписать эту функцию с использованием цикла for...of, вы можете заменить следующую строку:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
  const number = numbers[i];
```

на:

```
for (const number of numbers) {
```

Таким образом, вы будете итерироваться по массиву numbers, присваивая каждый элемент массива переменной number на каждой итерации цикла.

Полный код функции, переписанной с использованием цикла for...of, будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
function filterArray(numbers, value) {
  const filteredNumbers = [];

  for (const number of numbers) {
    if (number > value) {
      filteredNumbers.push(number);
    }
  }

  return filteredNumbers;
}
```